# Applying with someone who was rejected twice for US Visa

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

I am currently trying to apply for a B1/B2 Visa to attend a training in the US.

My colleague is also doing the same but he has already been denied twice last year. His past reason for applying is to attend a meeting in the US.

Will it hurt my chances if I apply the visa together with him? I put him as a travel companion in the DS-160 form.

Comment: What was the reason for your colleague’s denial and could the same reason apply to you?

Comment: It is Section 214(b). Maybe because the consul is not sold to the fact the my colleague will not be working there. If that is the case, will it also hurt my chances even if we are just really going to attend a training?

Comment: Why do you want to apply together with him? It’s not necessary

Comment: It's a very interesting question.  But surely, you should NOT mention the other person at all.  Why risk it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell what impact applying together will have. However, even if the two of you are called to the booth together (unlikely), your individual applications will be assessed separately.

I once applied with a relative. We were at the booth together but the consular interviewed us both one after the other. Then she told us that I was successful while my relative was not.

Unless your application is particularly strong, I would not risk applying together. Listing him as a travel buddy isn't really going to be an issue.